# Como fazer embedding de frases para NLP no TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Preciso transformar um banco de frases que eu mesmo criei em um vetor adequado para pode usa-lo como treinamento de uma rede neural no TensorFlow.
Tenho a seguinte estrutura:
[image]

Eu consegui separar as frases em palavras:
[image]

Contudo, eu gostaria de saber como fazer em parta transformar essas frases em um vetor de inteiros onde as palavras sejam substituídas por um índice.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use um objeto da classe *Tokenizer* do keras.

```
# criar objeto da classe Tokenizer():
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()

# construir o dicionário usado pelo tokenizer para converter em inteiros:
tokenizer.fit_on_texts( SUA LISTA DE FRASES DE REFERÊNCIA VAI AQUI)

# criar a lista de frases como sequência de inteiros:
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( SUA LISTA DE FRASES QUE DESEJA CONVERTER VAI AQUI)
```

O método *fit_on_texts()* pode ser chamado múltiplas vezes com argumentos diferentes. Cada vez que fizer o fit, as palavras que ainda não constam no dicionário vão ser incluídas. Para conferir como ficou o dicionário depois de fazer o fit, consulte o atributo *word_index*.

Dependendo de como for montar seu modelo, a classe *Tokenizer* tem outros métodos úteis, como o *texts_to_matrix()* e o *sentences_to_texts()*.

Mais detalhes aqui: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer

Uma pequena correção: o que você quer (transformar frase num vetor de inteiros) é feito por um tokenizer, que traduz as palavras para um número inteiro que vai de 1 até o tamanho do dicionário (quantidade de palavras conhecidas pelo tokenizer). Embedding é outra coisa, é transformar em um vetor de números reais, de dimensão reduzida (tipicamente 50-300 dimensões).

Comment: Consegui montar o modelo! Muito obrigado!